# SELECT query where two fields do NOT match not working

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an VBA script which looks through a table that is a join of two different tables (`a` and `b`), where there may be fields that don't match between the table (table `a` is the original, table `b` is the same table, but a new export file).

The goal is to find which field(s) differ and update one field in the shared field with a list of fields that did not match between the two tables (`a` and `b`).

But one field is not passing its test.  I tried separately querying this table to see if I could use a simple SQL query to determine if Access was recognizing the difference.

I cannot understand why this is not working, as if I try other fields in the same manner, it returns the expected result.  I have confirmed that both fields are `Short Text` data type, both fields have the same "General Properties", "Lookup Properties" and the "Property Sheet" also matches not only between the two fields, but all other similar fields.

This query:

```
SELECT [a_Address 2], [b_Address 2]
FROM Staging_LOG_ExportDifferences
WHERE ID = 18;
```

Results in:

```
[a_Address 2] = (NULL)
[b_Address 2] = xasdf
```

But when I try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Staging_LOG_ExportDifferences
WHERE [a_Address 2] <> [b_Address 2];
```

Results in:

```
No results
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the semantics of `NULL`.  It fails almost every comparison -- or more accurately, the comparison returns `NULL` which is filtered out along with `FALSE`.

Standard SQL has a `NULL`-safe comparison, `IS DISTINCT FROM`.  But MS Access doesn't support it.

So, you can be explicit:

```
SELECT *
FROM Staging_LOG_ExportDifferences
WHERE ([a_Address 2] <> [b_Address 2]) OR
      ([a_Address 2] IS NULL AND [b_Address 2] IS NOT NULL) OR
      ([a_Address 2] IS NOT NULL AND [b_Address 2] IS NULL) ;
```

Comment: This identified the issue.  I'm curious, how can I adjust my VBA part of the code to catch these?  right now I'm setting the value of the variable like this `CustAddress2A = exportDiffs.Fields("a_Address 2").Value`  then doing a string compare like such: `If StrComp(CustAddress1A, CustAddress1B, 1) <> 0 Then` `Result = Result + "Address2; "`                                                                         `Else: Result = Result`                                                                                            `End If`  How can I make sure I'm including these NULL workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use this approach, preventing you from having to use multiple if statements in VBA:

```
SELECT [a_Address 2], [b_Address 2]
FROM Staging_LOG_ExportDifferences
WHERE Len(Nz([a_Address 2],"")) <> Len(Nz([b_Address 2],""))
```

Comment: This will not work properly. If the two addresses are different but have the same length, it will result in a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Staging_LOG_ExportDifferences
WHERE Nz([a_Address 2],'') <> Nz([b_Address 2],'');
```

This assumes that your addresses do not contain empty strings or at least you consider an empty string "equal" to `NULL` for your comparison purposes. I generally also use `Trim` to make sure any mistyped spaces do not cause issues:

```
Trim(Nz([a_Address 2],'')) <> Trim(Nz([b_Address 2],''))
```